# Animated GIFs on MAC

Tags: animated-gif

So I have tried this and it didn't work. My Animated GIF plays once in a browser, but when I add it to Powerpoint it still loops. I used both Photoshop as well as https://ezgif.com/optimize/ website and the file only plays once, but loops endlessly in PPT. Help!

I tested in in Windows and it plays once, but on MAC is loops.

See my file online: http://tonyjuliendesign.com/test/masking-human-optimize-2.gif

Thanks